# Importing data from S3 to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to import a JSON file which has been uploaded into S3 into DynamoDB

I followed the tutorial amazon has given

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-console-start.html

But when i try to activate the pipeline the component TableLoadActivity fails and DDBDestinationTable says  CASCADE_FAILED

Both give the error

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:520) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:512) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:394) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I was getting the similar error , because I was selecting the exact json file . So the solution was to select the folder in which the json and manifest files are present

Comment: With the new built-in feature of import from S3, you just need to get the file into DynamoDB JSON or Amazon ION formats using AWS Glue and then DynamoDB accepts the file and then it will quickly make a new table for you with that data.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that you have to select the inner folder, where 'manifest' is present.
This use to be the folder with the backup's date and time.

I received this error when I have selected the parent folder, that I gave my table name.